# NASM on Virtual Machine Ubuntu: Cannot execute binary file exec format error

Tags: assembly, virtual-machine, nasm, x86-64, ld

I am getting an error after assembling a simple 64 bit hello world program.
I am using the following commands:

```
nasm -f elf64 hello.asm -o hello.o    successfull
ld -o hello.o hello -m elf_x86_64     successfull
./hello
```

error: Cannot execute binary file exec format error

I am executing this in a 64 bit Ubuntu Virtual Machine.
I appreciate your help!

Comment: Are you really using `ld -o hello.o hello -m elf_x86_64`? Looks like you want `ld -o hello hello.o -m elf_x86_64`

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you installed 64-bit Ubuntu? Maybe you installed 32-bit Ubuntu? What does `uname -a` show?

Comment: Hey i just checked, both ways im getting the same error.

Comment: Linux dell 3.16.0-50-generic #67~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri...i686 i686 i686 GNU/LINUX    uname -a

Comment: Please do the `uname -a` command and tell us what it outputs. As well before do the `ld` command do `rm hello` to make sure you don't have a junk file. Your version should not work. `ld -o hello.o hello` says to create an output file called `hello.o` from the file `hello`. that is not correct, and should throw an error unless you have a bogus file called `hello` laying around.

Comment: I tried ur suggestion but still the same error!! For your knowledge i have installed ubuntu on a virtual machine..

Comment: ok! so i can not use 64 bit operands on a 32 bit system??

Comment: You can not run a 64-bit apps on a 32-bit OS. You can install a 64-bit OS in the virtual machine, and if properly configured it can run 64-bit and 32-bit apps. It probably works on your friends system because he installed a 64-bit OS (Ubuntu?) inside his virtual machine. On his system run `uname -a` and I bet `x86_64` appears somewhere in the output.

Comment: So I need to install the 64 bit mode on VM!! Got it...Btw does the 32 bit version of the iso consists of option for 64 bit??? Thanks for your help!!

Comment: yes i used uname -a in the vm btw Thanks!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error:

> error: Cannot execute binary file exec format error

Suggests your system can't understand the executable you are trying to run. In my comments I asked you to run `uname -a` so that I can find out what type of system you are running in your virtual machine. You gave the output as:

```
Linux dell 3.16.0-50-generic #67~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri...i686 i686 i686 GNU/LINUX
```

The `i686` tells us this is a 32-bit version of Ubuntu, not 64-bit. Had the output included `x86_64` then you would be on a 64-bit Ubuntu.

A 32-Bit OS can't directly run 64-bit applications. If you need to generate and run 64-bit code you will need to install a 64-bit Ubuntu OS.

A 64-bit Ubuntu system can be configured to allow development of 32 and 64-bit code by using *multilib* support. If building software with C/C++ (or just the *C* libraries) it might be useful to install these packages on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib
```

---

Assuming you do install a 64-bit OS, the command you use to link your executable appears incorrect. You have:

```
nasm -f elf64 hello.asm -o hello.o    
ld -o hello.o hello -m elf_x86_64 
./hello
```

The *NASM* command looks okay. That assembles `hello.asm` to a 64-bit object file called `hello.o` . The *LD* command is being told to generate a 64-bit output file called `hello.o` from a file called `hello`. The commands should have looked like:

```
nasm -f elf64 hello.asm -o hello.o    
ld -o hello hello.o -m elf_x86_64 
./hello
```

Notice that we now use `-o hello` as we want to output an executable called `hello` from an object file called `hello.o`.

Comment: and with the 64-bit version of the OS installed, he should be able to simply rely on the default target and use `ld -o hello hello.o` as the link command, dropping `-m elf_x86_64` in its entirety.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin What you say is true, but leaving it in will still work, and it makes it clearer. You are correct the default would allow the `-m elf_x86_64` to be dropped if the OP so chooses.

Answer (score -1):

You may have 32-bit one, check once again. Also, as help says, there are more binary formats, try following: elfx32, elf32, elf.

Comment: Hi what do u mean by i may be having 32 bit one and yes i tried many binary formats while linking nothing seems to work. Also the program uses  64 bit registers. Thanks for helping

Comment: @user5444075 you may just use gas or yasm. They seem to be better

Comment: I would but my professors support nasm, and teach everything on nasm plus im still a learner! I'd like to add that the same program is working on my friends pc. I think this may be happening because of virtual machine, maybe??